# how does this error means in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement, react-router-dom

when I import switch from react-router-dom [error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0fDo.png)
when I import switch from react-router [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwI1Q.png)

I copied code from https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for error messages or text in general. Text in images can't be searched for and the image may become unavailable in the future. Instead simply paste the error text into your question.

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Switch is exported from "react-router", not from "react-router-dom"

Convert this:

```
import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

to:

```
import { Switch } from "react-router";
```

Comment: i got the same error, watch screen shot i have updated it

Answer (score 0):

Hello because Switch is exported from react-router

```
import { Switch } from "react-router";
```

Comment: same error with react-router , watch screen shot in updated question

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similiar problem with importing Switch from react-router-dom. In my case, I was using the latest (v6, i think) version of react-router-dom where the "Switch" is replaced by "Routes".

So either you check your react-router-dom's version and replace `Switch` to `Routes` and change the Route declaraton from `<Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />` to `<Route path="/" element={Dashboard} />` **if** it's v6, **or** you want to downgrade your react-router-dom version and keep using `Switch`.

Your call.

Comment: error goes but now it is showning me blank white screen on browser

Comment: could you pls look at the console tab (right click, inspect, console) and see if there is any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `npm i react-router-dom@5.2.0` this version `Switch` working in this version

Comment: thanks it worked , you are the best

Comment: If my anwer helps you then accept it ;)